# Optical properties of a single-walled carbon nanotube (10,0)

Tags: density-functional-theory, optical-properties

I hope you're well,
I am a beginner in the optical properties of carbon nanotubes, is there someone expert in carbon nanotubes who can verify with me its results,
[image]